# Improving talking skills

Tags: professionalism, communication

I am often using the fill words

> eh ehm uhm

Is there anyway to improve/minimize that behavior?

Comment: Why do you see this as a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would serve better on interpersonal skills, at the moment this has nothing to do with the work place: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Find a local Toast Masters club to join. They focus on improving public speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing your use of filler words to zero can be done. New news anchors and professional speakers do it all the time.

At one of my public speaking [Toastmasters](http://www.toastmasters.org/) clubs, we used clickers when someone used filler words and someone kept track of the number of clicks to see how we were progressing over time. However, not all Toastmasters clubs are that rigorous. You should visit a few before choosing one for yourself. Toastmasters clubs are basically [everywhere](http://www.toastmasters.org/find-a-club) and they can vary greatly.

If the club you choose doesn't have clickers, you can just purchase a bunch online and give it to your club. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LH9JCA) are the kind of clickers that I am talking about, although ours were different from those so I do not know if those are any good. Have one person in charge of the clickers. If you let people keep them, they'll forget them the next time you need them. Also, not everyone needs a clicker. A dozen should be more than enough. And leave the clickers at the center of the table if it's the first time someone is speaking or if that person doesn't want to work on that specific habit yet.

If you use filler words when speaking to your family or friends, you could ask them that they do the same to you. You could even reward them with a nickel or a quarter each time they catch you doing it (or more if you like). Just don't let it get out of hands. Make some ground rules. Tell them that if they click you or signal you in a place/situation where you do not wish to be clicked or signaled, they will be the one owing you that nickel or quarter.

Another thing a Toastmasters club should help you with is pauses. Silent pauses can be used to great effect. As audience members, we recognize the value of pauses, but as speakers, we often don't and we get nervous when we're not filling the air with sound.

But pausing is not the only trick that's available to you, if you work on structure, transitions, and endings, you should be able to minimize your use of filler words. For instance, if I already know that I am going to structure any impromptu table topic I receive with the structure of past, present, and future, then I don't need as much time figuring out what to say when improvising because by then, I'm just filling up those three slots one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can :-)
Generally this behaviour is caused by the fact that you want to start to say something before your mind is prepared about what you want to say. This can be handled very simply by waiting a bit before actually starting to speak.

So simple? Yes and no:
Yes, just by waiting (just half a second) you will automatically reduce saying those things.
No, because you're dealing with other persons too, and there's the catch: generally you start saying things like "eh", "heu", ... when you are in a hurry starting speaking, and this is regularly caused by the other people around you: the people around you are used that you start speaking quite quickly, so in order to say something they are doing this very quickly, and before you realise you end up in a speaking contest, and the one who is the first to start talking, wins the contest. In other words, when you wait, even for just half a second, you might end up loosing every speaking contest.

I propose you to start experimenting with the waiting thing outside of the daily speaking contests, e.g. you are in a meeting, you mention that you want to say something (e.g. by raising your hand), and while everybody is expecting you to say something, you do the waiting trick and then you start speaking. Be aware, this is very difficult: everybody is expecting you to say something and instead of starting to speak, you remain silent for half a second. (I've been there, I know how hard it is) But you'll soon find out that that half a second is not that long, and once you speak more fluently you'll earn more respect from the people around the table, and that confidence will stimulate you to go on with the waiting trick.

Good luck and keep us informed about your progress

Answer (score 0):

This is my way for effective speaking. As a US raised individual, my cultural upbringing might not work in yours.

> eh ehm uhm

Say these words in your mind. In fact, repeat the question that was asked of you in your head and run the reply in your head first. After you've decided that the response is valid, then say it. This will help keep things nice and concise. After a bit of training, all the ahh's and umm's in the world will happen in your mind. Don't worry you aren't going crazy. You are just choosing what sounds to vocalize.

Now as for physiological tools, I would recommend the "look away" strategy. In western culture, making eye contact is a means of indicating attention between two individuals. If you divert your eyes (either up or down) it allows you a physical break of allowing you to concentrate on your broca's area (speech center) rather than your eyes (visual cortex).